# Qué puede llegar a pasar si se pone en false el valor true del curl_setopt($connect, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true)?

Tags: php

Qué puede llegar a pasar si se pone en false el valor true del `curl_setopt($connect, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true)`?

probe en un sitio no seguro y funciona bien todo.

Puede haber algún problema con Mercado Pago al modificar ese valor,o sólo correría peligro exponer mis credenciales `CLIENT_ID`" y "`CLIENT_SECRET`" en un sitio no seguro?

por ej en un sitio localhost en true no funciona, no devuelve el `pereference_id`

lo mismo en un sitio online.

la libreria `mercadopago.php` por defecto viene en true ese valor

Answer (score 0):

Como bien dices, con un sitio no seguro no hay diferencia.

La diferencia está cuando intentes leer un sitio seguro (`https://...`).

Como curl no tiene los certificados de las empresas certificadoras que los navegadores sí traen por defecto, cuando está a `true` intenta verificar el certificado que te manda la página y dará error. No porque el certificado sea inválido, sino porque no puede comprobarlo.

Si lo pones a `false` aceptará como bueno cualquier certificado. Eso significa que si te hacen un [man-in-the-middle](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ataque_de_intermediario) no te vas a enterar. Es un fallo de seguridad muy grave.